# MySQL query to get a particular rank

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, mysql-variables

I have a query on MySQL database working in a such way that I get this result:

```
> Rank  Gold    Silver  Bronze  Total 
> 1     76      78      77      231 
> 2     4       5       6       15 
> 3     4       1       1       6
> 4     3       0       0       3 
> 5     2       1       1       4 
> 5     2       1       1       4
> 6     2       0       0       2
> 7     1       1       1       3
> 8     1       1       0       2
> 9     1       0       2       3
> 9     1       0       2       3
> 9     1       0       2       3
> 10    0       1       0       1
```

The query from which I get this result is the following (I hide the main query not to wright too much code):

```
select
    CASE
        WHEN (@Gold=T.Gold and @Silver=T.Silver and @Bronze=T.Bronze) THEN @rownum ELSE @rownum:=@rownum+1 end as Rank,        

        (@Gold:=T.Gold) Gold,
        (@Silver:=T.Silver) Silver,
        (@Bronze:=T.Bronze) Bronze,
        T.Total

from

(MAIN_QUERY) T,

(SELECT @rownum:=0) r, 
    (SELECT @Gold:=0) g,
    (SELECT @Silver:=0) s,
    (SELECT @Bronze:=0) b

   order by Gold desc, Silver DESC, Bronze DESC
```

But instead the reuslt above, I'd like to adjust the Rank coloumn (and my query) increasing it depending on the duplicated previous rows, i.e.:

```
> Rank  Gold    Silver  Bronze  Total 
    > 1     76      78      77      231 
    > 2     4       5       6       15 
    > 3     4       1       1       6
    > 4     3       0       0       3 
    > 5     2       1       1       4 
    > 5     2       1       1       4
    > 7     2       0       0       2
    > 8     1       1       1       3
    > 9     1       1       0       2
    > 10    1       0       2       3
    > 10    1       0       2       3
    > 10    1       0       2       3
    > 13    0       1       0       1
```

and so on.
Can you help me to get this result?

Comment: What about rank 6 in the example above? And what's the expected criteria for this expected ranking

Comment: If it was me, I'd have a column for country, a column for colour, and a column for quantity, and take it from there.

Comment: @hankypanky that's the point. The op wants to handle ties in the same that a sports scoreboard would

Comment: But then does a real score board skip a whole rank? Its fine to have two teams on rank 5 but is it also fine to have 0 teams on rank 6 then resume from 7?

Comment: You could introduce another variable with a group counter. If no one answers, ping me.

Comment: maybe you could add a sqlfiddle to illustrate

Comment: @Drew: yes, I tried to use another variable for group counter but with no results. Maybe I was wrong something. How could you do? Can you help me?

Comment: Sure. You need to add a sqlfiddle with data and your your entire query. Please set all that up and I will take a look

Answer (score 2):

Maybe another variable can do this:

```
SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1, 
       CASE 
         WHEN ( @gold = T.gold 
                AND @silver = T.silver 
                AND @bronze = T.bronze ) THEN @rank := @rank 
         ELSE @rank := @rownum 
       END                     AS Rank, 
       ( @gold := T.gold )     Gold, 
       ( @silver := T.silver ) Silver, 
       ( @bronze := T.bronze ) Bronze, 
       T.total 
FROM   (MAIN_QUERY) T 
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0, 
                          @gold := 0, 
                          @silver := 0, 
                          @bronze := 0, 
                          @rank := 0) v 
ORDER  BY gold DESC, 
          silver DESC, 
          bronze DESC
```

[<kbd>Here is a demo</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ce04ec/5)

***NOTE:*** If all columns of your data are 0, this will not work.

Comment: The MySQL manual makes it clear that the ordering of which select columns are computed are not guaranteed. So this is not a safe strategy. Please see [This](http://i.imgur.com/r6avUZT.jpg). So getting it to work in a fiddle is one thing. But I would never deploy it to production.

Comment: @Drew Hmm, right. What if `order by` in main query?

Comment: I created the tag above to house some as I restumble onto them. `mysql-variables` . Only a few of us on the stack write up the answers the safe way. There is the Baron's [Obligatory Reading](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/15/advanced-mysql-user-variable-techniques/) blog where he finds safety in `greatest()`. Things can be cleansed with `least()`, `greatest()`, and `coalesce()` or layers of `if` stmts that seem to make no sense but there is method to the madness.

Comment: But they are time consuming. So one's biorhythms and mojo have to be into it at the moment. Plus the question has to be well setup.